# error when i trying to close my application vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have programmed a small program with `vb.net` with `mysql`. it is working fine . but while closing my application using "End" command. I'm getting this error.

> "System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2147467261`enter code here`   Message=Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.   Source=MySql.Data   StackTrace:
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.FetchDataRow(Int32 statementId, Int32 columns)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.FetchDataRow(Int32 statementId, Int32 columns)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.SkipDataRow()
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.Close()
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Close()
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Close()
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>          at System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize()   InnerException: "

its only appears when while closing my application. please help me. thank you.

Comment: Show your code please for better understanding.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

It will be less difficult to answer if you put some of your code here.
May be you don't close a MySql Reader or Connection before closing your program.

Comment: i found the problem. i was declared connection string in a module.
then i removed it and separately declared it on every form that i using mysql. now that error is gone. and code is working fine. but i cant figure out why is that happen when i using a module to connect my database. if you know please let me know. and note ms sql is connecting fine by module. errors is only come when i trying to use mysql. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use something that is null (or Nothing in VB.NET). This means you either set it to null, or you never set it to anything at all.

**What This Really Means**

The runtime throwing a NullReferenceException always means the same thing: you are trying to use a reference. The reference is not initialized (or it was initialized, but is no longer initialized).

This means the reference is null, and you cannot access members through a null reference. The simplest case:

```
string name = null;
name.ToUpper();
```

or

```
string name = null;
name.ToLower();
```

These will throw a NullReferenceException at the second line, because you can't call the instance method ToUpper() or ToLower() on a string reference pointing to null.

Comment: thank you for your rply. but i found the problem. i was declared connection string in a module. then i removed it and separately declared it on every form that i using mysql. now that error is gone. and code is working fine. but i cant figure out why is that happen when i using a module to connect my database. if you know please let me know. and note ms sql is connecting fine by module. errors is only come when i trying to use mysql. thank you

Comment: so you where not declaring it at all as i mentioned above. Sorry i can't help any further.